# Two equivalent definitions of the outer measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\mu^*$ be an outer measure on the power set of $X$. Furthermore, be that this outer measure was induced by a premeasure $\mu\colon \mathcal{A}\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ on a semiring $\mathcal{A}$

Given two sets (denote power set of $X$ as $2^X$):

$\displaystyle \mathcal{M}(\mu^*):=\{ A\in 2^X\colon\ \mu^*(E)=\mu^*(E\cap A)+\mu^*(E\cap A^c),\ \forall E\in 2^X\}$

$\displaystyle \mathcal{M}'(\mu^*):=\{ A\in 2^X\colon\ \mu^*(E)=\mu^*(E\cap A)+\mu^*(E\cap A^c),\ \forall E\in \sigma(\mathcal{A})\}$

I want to show that $\mathcal{M}'(\mu^*)=\mathcal{M}(\mu^*)$.

However, I seem to be stuck right at the beginning, as none of my approaches was promising so far.

Note that of course we have $\mathcal{M}(\mu^*)\subset\mathcal{M}'(\mu^*)$, so we need just to show that $\mathcal{M'}(\mu^*)\subset\mathcal{M}(\mu^*)$.

Also note that, since the outer measure is $\sigma$-subadditive, it would be enough to consider $\mu^*(E)\ge\mu^*(E\cap A)+\mu^*(E\cap A^c)$ for any $E$.

Then we would need to prove that this inequality if it holds for an $A\in2^X$ for all $E\in\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ hold for all $E\in 2^X$. As I said all my approaches to do this failed.